# Enterprise Keywords in Search refinement

Tags: enterprise-search, refinement-panel, keyword

I would like to add a refiment category on my search page that displays my Enterprise keywords that the content has been tagged with. However I have some problems as the keywords doesn't show up in my refinement. I have verified in my search xml that the ows_metadatafacetinfo field returns data and I have tried to catch this in my refinement category of the TaxonomyFilterGenerator type but with no result. I have also tried to change the title of my category to the swedish translation of TaxKeyword (Företagsnyckelord) but it still doesn't show my refinement category.

```
<ows_metadatafacetinfo>TaxKeyword|Företagsnyckelord|hR+9Zui2N0Cngd7QElDSsg==|2+Rhh6LFxkWDHNP5QQEXUg==|#c76e8472-4b10-4bc5-9b78-8629c8c85e79|test;#</ows_metadatafacetinfo>"

<Category Title="TaxKeyword"
 Description=""
 Type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.TaxonomyFilterGenerator"
 MetadataThreshold="1"
 NumberOfFiltersToDisplay="4"
 MaxNumberOfFilters="20"
 SortBy="Frequency"
 SortByForMoreFilters="Name"
 SortDirection="Descending"
 SortDirectionForMoreFilters="Ascending"
 ShowMoreLink="True"
 MappedProperty="ows_MetadataFacetInfo"
 MoreLinkText="visa mer"
 LessLinkText="visa färre"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the box "Use Location Visualization" - otherwise the default is used.